Mapping for JsonNode fails after migrating to SpringBoot 3.x
In Hibernate 5.x I used to register hibernate type like:
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect;

import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.IntArrayType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeBinaryType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeStringType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;

public class PostgreSQLJsonDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {
    public PostgreSQLJsonDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, StringArrayType.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, IntArrayType.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonStringType.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonBinaryType.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType.class.getName());
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeStringType.class.getName());
    }
}

But post migration, I can no longer register these types.
the above code is now changed to:
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect;

public class PostgreSQLJsonDialect extends PostgresPlusDialect {
    public PostgreSQLJsonDialect() {
        super();
    }
}

I have an entity which previously looked like:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
....
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class Work {
        @Column(name = "output", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @JsonProperty("output")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private JsonNode output;
        ......
        ......

currently after the migration it looks like:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;
....
public class Work {
        @Column(name = "output", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @JsonProperty("output")
    @Type(JsonType.class)
    private JsonNode output;
        ......
        ......

and my repository code looks like:
public interface WorkRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, UUID> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT output FROM work WHERE job_id = :jobId AND type = :type ORDER BY ended_at DESC LIMIT 1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<JsonNode> getLatestOutput(String type, UUID jobId);

}

I want to be able to fetch the data in JsonNode format.
I tried to resolveSqlTypeDescriptor like this:
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JdbcType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.spi.JdbcTypeRegistry;
import org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration;

import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeBinaryType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeStringType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonStringType;
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonType;

public class PostgreSQLJsonDialect extends PostgresPlusDialect {
    public PostgreSQLJsonDialect() {
        super();
        final TypeConfiguration typeConfiguration = new TypeConfiguration();
        final JdbcTypeRegistry jdbcTypeRegistry = new JdbcTypeRegistry(typeConfiguration);
        this.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(new JsonBinaryType().getName(), 0, 0, 0, jdbcTypeRegistry);
        this.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(new JsonNodeBinaryType().getName(), 0, 0, 0, jdbcTypeRegistry);
        this.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(new JsonType().getName(), 0, 0, 0, jdbcTypeRegistry);
        this.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(new JsonStringType().getName(), 0, 0, 0, jdbcTypeRegistry);
        this.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(new JsonNodeStringType().getName(), 0, 0, 0, jdbcTypeRegistry);
    }

    @Override
    public JdbcType resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(final String columnTypeName, int jdbcTypeCode, final int precision, final int scale, final JdbcTypeRegistry jdbcTypeRegistry) {
        jdbcTypeCode = SqlTypes.OTHER;
        return super.resolveSqlTypeDescriptor(columnTypeName, jdbcTypeCode, precision, scale, jdbcTypeRegistry);
    }
}

But this is still not working and I am getting an error:
error message
How can I register JsonNode so that I am able to fetch the data in JsonNode format?
PS: This question was also asked in the hibernate forum:
https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/mapping-for-jsonnode-in-hibernate-6-2-fails-after-migration-from-hibernate-5-x/9416

Why is this a native query and not a regular JPQL query?  Which should let the JPA mapping kick in instead of a plain result trying to be converted by Spring Data. Next you upgraded, did you also upgrade the Hypersistence utils to compatible versions? I do believe you don't need additional configuration (and the JsonNodeStringType shouldn't be used on PostgreSQL according to the documentation).

@M.Deinum thanks for your comment. We did updated to latest version and changed the native query to JPQL and it worked :)
